# Compilation error in Ubuntu: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, makefile

I'm a newbie when it comes to the compilation process, and in Linux too, but I do know something. I have some source code, which I want to compile.

I've executed `apt-get install build-essential`, but it doesn't really help me.

When I execute `make` I receive this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llog
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Some files do compile successfully, but for some I get this error. As I research more it seems due to a missing library.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: How are you trying to compile?  Can you post the steps?

Comment: Are you trying to compile an opensource project? which package/project?

Comment: Can you say a little more about the software you're trying to compile? Is a software you wrote? Is a software you downloaded?

Comment: **What exactly** are you trying to compile?   It refers to a library called liblog which does not seem to be installed on your system or at least not in the libary search path in effect.  You need to figure out what this library is which it wants.  You could also try removing the -llog - if you didn't get an earlier error about a missing .h file or resulting missing function prototype, you might not actually need it (ie, might not actually be being used).

Comment: I have project writed in QT. I installed QT library as it says in documentation. Then i go to my project `cd ~/projects/myproject`, then i run `qmake` (all this steps was running withut errors) and finaly `make`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly what you need is to install these packages:

```
 sudo apt-get install liblog4cplus-dev liblog4cpp5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you specifically wrote "I make apt-get install ... " I think i need to clarify. But maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Usually when you're doing make install, you're require to make install some file in a source directory

```
#download the source of whatever you're installing
wget <someSource>

#go to it
cd /mySourceFolder/

# make, make install
make [-someFlags]
make install
```

Alternatively, if you use `apt-get install`, its just that.

```
apt-get install <nameOfInstallee>
```